# Should I have different collections for different users in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, architecture, database

Im new to databases and mongo. I'm creating a web app that has different types of users that have access to different routes via different UI's. eg: user, company, admin. My question is should I create a single collection that houses all users and simple add a "user-type" or "access-level" as a property on each User object? or should I have 3 different Collections, one for each type of user?

What is common practice for this type of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What would be fields for each type of user? If they are same, use user type option.  Same user can be in multiple roles tomorrow. Storing in same collection would be better.

If the fields to be stored are completely different, and there is not a chance that same user can be in 2 roles ever in your application, use 3 collections.

Answer (score 0):

By  your question your Schema can have Roles set as **ENUM** and value as `user, company, admin.` and role should be accordingly set while you save the data to db

```
    var UserSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    last_name: {
        type: String
    }, Roles: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['USER', 'COMPANY', 'ADMIN'],
        default: 'ACTIVE'
    }
});
UserSchema.index({
    username: 1,
    role: 1
});
```

Comment: What if we want to have a user both in admin and company but must have extra fields? Can we use more collections and reference them?